# How can I make my batch script for deletion of old files work?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, scripting

Inside a folder (say c:\test) I want to delete the oldest file if the number of files are over 21.

This is what I came up with, issue is that it one time deletes the oldest file, second run it does nothing and deletes the oldest for third, continues like that. Also it doesn't care if the file amount is lower than 21, deletes even if it is lower.

Here is the code:

```
SET BACKUPDIR=C:\test
SET countfiles=dir BACKUPDIR /b | find /v /c "::"

if countfiles GTR 21 (
FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /B /O-D %BACKUPDIR%') DO SET OLDEST=%%i
DEL %BACKUPDIR%\%OLDEST%
)
```

Comment: I was going to try debugging this myself for you, but how about I just tell you what I would do. First, stick in some echo statements. After the first two `SET` statements add a line `echo countfiles = %countfiles%` and `echo BACKUPDIR = %BACKUPDIR%`. Then add a line inside your `IF` statement like `echo countfiles appears > 21`. Simple debugging techniques that might allow you to discover the fault yourself.

Comment: @PP: I thik that will be a good answer or at least a good pointer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's an alternative in vbscript, that iterates the directory just once.

```
Set objFS=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
strFolder = objArgs(0)
strScriptName = WScript.ScriptFullName 'get script name
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 
current  = Now
temp=0
count=0 'count files
For Each strFile In objFolder.Files
    If strFile.Path <> strScriptName Then 'do if not script name
      count=count+1
      dict.Add strFile.Path, strFile.DateLastModified
      'if there are more than 21 files
      If count >= 21 Then
        flag=1
      End If
    End If
Next

filedate = dict.Items
filename = dict.keys
If flag = 1 Then
    For i = 0 To dict.Count -1 'iterate dictionary
      diffdate = DateDiff("d",filedate(i),now)
      If num_days_diff >= temp Then
        oldestfile = filename(i)
        oldestdate = filedate(i)
        temp = num_days_diff
      End If             
    Next
End If 
Set dict=Nothing
WScript.Echo "Oldest file: " & oldestfile, oldestdate
objFS.DeleteFile(oldestfile)
```

save as deletefile.vbs and on command line

```
c:\test> cscript /nologo deletefile.vbs c:\path\somewhere
```

Comment: thanks alot for the input however I see an issue at this, it doesn't work unless you put it to "C:\test". And if I run it under "C:\test", it deletes itself :) I am very alien to vbscripting, how can it work to run it from a distant directory (ie executing it from "C:\". Cheers

Comment: you can use arguments. I have edited to include argument. What do you mean delete "itself?"

Comment: it was working only if I put it to the directory of the files, and as the script itself is a file, it was deleting the script file :)

Comment: its rather easy to add a "if" clause to check for script name. see edited

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of problems with this.

1. Environment variables vs. literal strings:

   ```
   SET countfiles=dir BACKUPDIR /b | find /v /c "::"
   ```

   Here you're trying to list files in a directory named "BACKUPDIR", instead of using the environment variable. It should be

   ```
   SET countfiles=dir %BACKUPDIR% /b | find /v /c "::"
   ```
2. Your try of getting the number of files:

   ```
   SET countfiles=dir %BACKUPDIR% /b | find /v /c "::"
   ```

   can't possibly work. This simply assigns the string `'dir BACKUPDIR /b | find /v /c "::"
   '` to the environment variable `countfiles`. It won't run anything—how should `cmd` know that this is a command to execute?

   What you want is the following:

   ```
   for /f %%x in ('dir %BACKUPDIR% /b ^| find /v /c "::"') do set countfiles=%%x
   ```

   This will set the contents of the `countfiles` environment variable to the output of above command. You can find more information on that with [`help for`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx).
3. Your comparison:

   ```
   if countfiles GTR 21
   ```

   this compares the *string* `"countfiles"` and the string `"21"`. And since `countfiles` gets sorted after `21`, this condition will always be true.

   You want to use the environment variable `%countfiles%` here:

   ```
   if %countfiles% GTR 21
   ```
4. You try "normal" variable expansion inside a "block":

   ```
   if %countfiles% GTR 21 (
       FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /B /O-D %BACKUPDIR%') DO SET OLDEST=%%i
       DEL %BACKUPDIR%\%OLDEST%
   )
   ```

   Since `cmd` expands environment variables immediately when parsing a command this leads to problems. Note that a block like above counts as a single command for `cmd`. The complete block will be parsed be fore it's run and all variables inside are replaced already when it runs, so that's not the right way to deal with variables that might change *inside* that block.

   The solution here is *delayed expansion*. You can include the following line at the start of your batch:

   ```
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   ```

   and instead of using the variable like `%OLDEST%` you use `!OLDEST!`. The `!` expand variables too, but do so directly before execution instead of while parsing. So your snippet would become:

   ```
   if %countfiles% GTR 21 (
       FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR /B /O-D %BACKUPDIR%') DO SET OLDEST=%%i
       DEL %BACKUPDIR%\!OLDEST!
   )
   ```
5. Just in case you are expecting file names with spaces, the `for /f` loop in the last block doesn't work as expected. You can modify it like this:

   ```
   for /f "delims=" %%i in ...
   ```

   This ensures that the line isn't broken at spaces (you would have got just the first token–up to the first space in the file name–instead of the complete file name.

So, summarizing, your program could look like the following:

```
SET BACKUPDIR=C:\test
for /f %%x in ('dir %BACKUPDIR% /b ^| find /v /c "::"') do set countfiles=%%x

if %countfiles% GTR 21 (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR /B /O-D %BACKUPDIR%') DO SET OLDEST=%%i
    DEL %BACKUPDIR%\!OLDEST!
)
```

and should roughly work. I haven't tested every aspect of it (bed calls) but I'm confident it works way better than before and I hope you understand above fixes and why they are necessary.

By the way: `find /v /c "::"` is a nifty little trick. Didn't know that one or thought of it.

Just in case: If you actually wanted to continue deleting the oldest file until your file count drops below 21, then that single `if` won't cut it. You need to set up a loop, either by continuing to iterate and re-count every iteration or by just calculating how many files you have to delete. I'll leave this as an exercise, though. (Hint: Loops can be done with labels and conditional `goto`s or by using `for /l`. The latter one will require more delayed expansion, though, so be careful.)

Comment: Thanks alot for the input Johannes, especially showing me my mistakes, as I am more oriented with Linux (so bash scripting) it was an interesting experience. Meanwhile the code you suggest somehow does not work. Here is the screenshot that will probably explain everything :) : http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/2199/deletex.jpg 
Best regards

Comment: Argh, I'm utterly sorry I missed that one. You should put the `BACKUPDIR` in your `dir` command in `%` too: `dir %BACKUPDIR% /b` to sue the environment variable and not try finding a directory named "BACKUPDIR".